# On a unix system that is running Tomcat, how do I find the URL path and not localhost:8080/

Tags: tomcat

Tomcat appears to be running on the system I'm using. Nobody seems to know what the URL path is to load the application running in it. Based on the server.xml file I believe I know what port but nothing I try loads any pages default or application wise.

Is there some specific tag set in this server.xml that depicts this information?

I'm not talking about using localhost:8080 or anything with localhost. There is not GUI on the server to try things out so I am connecting to the server and I cannot seem to figure out the url path after the server to get at the deployments.

Comment: Did you try with server ip or server name, I assume ip will work as you are using a non standard http port

Comment: @plykkegaard yes both fqdn and the ip. I see nothing at all coming into the logs for any attempts.

Comment: It is a TLS issue that is preventing things from working.

Comment: Word of advice use the 'top' to find your PID and then run the lsof -l -P -n | grep pid | grep LISTEN, this will show you the port you are listening on.

Comment: Seems you already know where `server.xml` is so most probably the apps are on a [sibling `webapps`directory](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/introduction.html) were you could have `app1`, `app2` directories. Each of those represent a context path like `http://server:8080/app1`

Comment: It is a possibility that you have more than one Tomcat server directories on the server. The Tomcat that is running is from another directory. As suggested above, try to figure out the PID. Another way would be to search the server for any 'server.xml'. Another way would be to scan the server with nmap and get list of open ports and try the non standard ports (very time consuming). Give it a shot and see if the above work